# Generating List Permutations of Variable Sequence Lenghts

Tags: python, regex, algorithm, permutation

Suppose I have a list that looks like this:

`beast = ['E', 'O', 'R', 'E', 'O', 'S', 'P', 'E', 'P', 'P', 'O', 'R', 'S', 'P', 'O', 'E']`

Now, here are the basic patterns that I want to extract:

```
basic_oros = ['O', 'R', 'O']

pi_poro = ['P', 'O', 'R', 'O']

pi_orpo = ['O', 'R', 'P', 'O']

pi_porpo = ['P', 'O', 'R', 'P', 'O']

si_orso = ['O', 'R', 'S', 'O']

spi_orspo = ['O', 'R', 'S', 'P', 'O']

spi_porso = ['P', 'O', 'R', 'S', 'O']

spi_porspo = ['P', 'O', 'R', 'S', 'P', 'O']
```

The problem is, if I extract only `['P', 'O', 'R', 'S', 'P', 'O']` out of `beast`, I miss out on the previous `P` before that pattern occurs.

(Better example - There can also be `['O', 'O', 'R', 'O', 'O', 'O']`)

Therefore, every letter in those basic patterns can be expanded in a sense of:

> Os can occur together thrice.
>
> Ps can occur together twice.
>
> Rs can occur together twice.
>
> Ss can occur only once.

I want to generate a list of all possible permutations but have no idea where to start.

I wrote a naive python code that replaces every occurrence of O with three Os and etc. But that results in -

`['O', 'O', 'O', 'R' 'O', 'O', 'O']`

Which won't work when I need to find:
`['O', 'R', 'O', 'O']`

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: This actually sounds like a job for regexes.

Comment: On lists? I've never used Regex before.

Comment: You can't perform a regex search in `beast` directly, but you can perform one on `''.join(beast)`.

Comment: Can you help form a regex pattern?

Comment: `r'O{1,3}R{1,2}O{1,3}'` for `basic_oros`, for example.

Comment: Ah. Thank you. :D Can you add this answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a job for regexes. If you join your `beast` list into a string with `''.join(beast)`, you can build regexes to search it for substrings matching specific patterns. For example, using the `{m,n}` quantifier to search for a certain number of repetitions of a subpattern, you can use

```
re.search(r'O{1,3}R{1,2}O{1,3}', ''.join(beast))
```

to search for a pattern consisting of 1 to 3 Os, 1 to 2 Rs, and 1 to 3 more Os.

See the [`re` module documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) for more information on Python's regex syntax and functions, and see any number of online tutorials for help getting used to writing regexes.